# change citation style using achemso?

Tags: citing, achemso

I'm using this class for a document, but I would like to have my citations like this:

```
[1] A. Einstein, 1912, Relativity, ...
```

instead of:

```
[1] Einstein, A., 1912, Relativity, ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `achemso` package should probably only be used for submissions to the Amer­i­can Chem­i­cal So­ci­ety in which case you should not alter the style (you can choose the alternative style `biochem` though with the `biochem` class option). In particular the package effectively disables `\bibnliographystyle` and does not let you choose your own style.

Comment: If you are using the `achemso` class, you should be aware that it is _purely_ for submission to the ACS, and so the bibliography style is prescribed.

Comment: @moewe The package forces a bibliography style because it's really a way to provide a convenient interface to controlling just that: there's no obvious reason (to me) to load it unless you want the ACS bibliography format!